# ReasonML Quick Start failing to compile

Tags: reason

After following the instruction on the quick start page of ReasonML, the command `npm run start` fails to compile the application.

It shows that the code has a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is using a new syntax now. But the quick start app is not updated yet. Go to src > demo.re and change the line:

`Js.log "Hello world";`

to something like this:

`Js.log("Hello World");`